# Color Variables but Alpha Separate

Tags: python, pygame

I stored all basic colors in variables for example:

```
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
```

I then use those variables to draw ellipes, but i want different alpha values for those ellipses. I dont want to create variables for all the different alpha values. I tried doing

```
pygame.draw.ellipse(self.image, (WHITE, 50), self.rect)
```

But that does not work sadly. Any Solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tuples can be concatenated by addition:

```
pygame.draw.ellipse(self.image, WHITE + (50,), self.rect)
```

---

For example,

```
>>> (255, 255, 255) + (50,)
(255, 255, 255, 50)
```

Lists, by the way, behave analogously:

```
>>> [255, 255, 255] + [50]
[255, 255, 255, 50]
```